# PHP5 Class scope quirks

Tags: php, oop, class, self

Hey php gurus. I'm running into some bizarre class scope problems that clearly have to do with some quirk in php. Can anyone tell me what out-of-the-ordinary situations might give the following error...

**Fatal error**:  Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in  **MyClass.php on line 5**

Now, obviously if I were to use self:: outside of the class, I'd get errors... but I'm not. Here is a simplified version of the situation...

```
//file1
class MyClass{
   public static function search($args=array()){
       $results = MyDbObject::getQueryResults("some query");
       $ordered_results = self::stack($results); //Error occurs here

       return $ordered_results;
   }
   public static function stack($args){
       //Sort the results
       return $ordered_results;
   }
}

//file 2
include_once("MyClass.php");
$args = array('search_term'=>"Jimmy Hoffa");
$results = MyClass::search($args);
```

given this setup how can I get the error above? Here is what I've found so far...

```
MyClass::search($args) //does not give the error (usually)
call_user_func("MyClass::search"); // this gives the error!
```

Any other situations?

Comment: another situation where the problem pops up is when you have a function within a class function. But I don't get why that should be a problem because the inner function still should be within the scope of the class, right? Obviously the inner function won't be accessible outside of the enclosing function. However it seems that you should be able to use self within the inner function.

Comment: What happens if you change "self::" to "MyClass::"?

Comment: then it works, but the code becomes substantially less reusable

Comment: Brooks: Obviously you cannot use `self` within the inner function ;) It is *not* in the class scope. As concerning your code above I see no fault. But `call_user_function("MyClass::search")` should actually not work at all... a) It's called `call_user_func` and b) you must pass it `array('MyClass', 'search')`.

Comment: (with PHP 5.3.x) should you be using the static keyword instead of self? $ordered_results = static::stack($results);

Comment: @nikic. Thanks. Sorry, typo on the first bit.  I meant call_user_func("MyClass::search"). Not using arrays is permissible as of 5.2.3 but I'll check to see if using the array syntax eliminates the limitation.

Comment: @Viper_Sb When a class doesn't have parent class, self and static are interchangeable, right? So static would presumably have the same limitation? Worth testing. Thanks.

Comment: found another one. 5.3.x seems to be ok with calling uasort($instances,"self::cmp"); from within a class function. Earlier earlier versions whine about it. I assume it's the same for similar functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). This feature requires PHP version 5.3 at least.

Comment: The problem here is that there seem to be situations in which you can call a class method without loading the class's scope. It's not a problem with inheritance that can be resolved by late static binding.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing any parameters, but your method is looking for them.  Try

```
call_user_func("MyClass::search", $args);
```

This works in php 5.3.1, but `call_user_func("MyClass::search");` doesn't

Comment: This is correct, I just tried it in PHP 5.3.x and it works fine you just need the args, with <5.2.x it'll give you that error. Code I used class MyClass{
   public static function search($args){
       $results = "some query";
       $ordered_results = self::stack($results);

       return $ordered_results;
   }
   public static function stack($args){
       //Sort the results
       return 'query some';
   }
}
$args = array('search_term'=>"Jimmy Hoffa");
print call_user_func("MyClass::search", $args);

Comment: You missed the point of the question entirely. Read the question not the code. I'm not trying to get something to work, I'm trying to identify a set of limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'search'));
```

See also example #4 on http://php.net/call_user_func

Comment: You can pass static object methods as the first param

Comment: But doesn't that require PHP 5.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. If there's something wrong with it, I must be missing the problem. It appears that your call to self:: is totally within the scope of a class! And a static scope, specifically, which is what self:: is for.

From the 3rd Edition of PHP Objects Patterns and Practice (an awesome book):

> To access a static method or property from within the same class
>   (rather than from a child), I would use the self keyword. self is to
>   classes what the $this pseudo-variable is to objects. So from outside
>   the StaticExample class, I access the $aNum property using its class
>   name:
>
> ```
> StaticExample::$aNum;
> ```
>
> From within the StaticExample class I can use the self keyword:
>
> ```
> class StaticExample {`
>     static public $aNum = 0;
>
>     static public function sayHello() {
>         self::$aNum++;
>         print "hello (".self::$aNum.")\n";
>     }
> }
> ```

So, I am not sure why this code was failing. Perhaps a PHP bug? I came upon this error when actually trying to use self:: outside of the scope of a class-- my error looked like this:

```
public static function get_names() {
    $machine_names = self::get_machine_names();

    return array_map(function ($machine_name) {
        $service_settings = self::get_settings_by_machine_name($machine_name);
        return $service_settings . $machine_name;
        },
        $machine_names
    );
}
```

So, I get the error because I use self:: within the scope of the closure. To fix the error, I could make that call to self::get_settings_by_machine_name() before the closure, and pass the results to the closure's scope with `use`.

Not sure what was happening in your code.